# Doctrine Unit Test created_at field failure

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony3 with doctrine ORM
I am Testing a controller action, but the assertion fails because of created at is different

```
public function testGetOneJobFound()
{
    $expected = '{"id":"a961c741-1c32-11ea-bfc6-0242ac130003","service_id":804040,"zipcode_id":"10115","title":"title","description":"decription","date_to_be_done":"2018-11-11T00:00:00+00:00","created_at":"2019-12-11T14:55:48+00:00"}';

    $this->client->request('GET', '/job/a961c741-1c32-11ea-bfc6-0242ac130003');

    $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Unit test result:
Time: 4.49 seconds, Memory: 22.00MB

There was 1 failure:

```
1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\JobControllerTest::testGetOneJobFound
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'{"id":"a961c741-1c32-11ea-bfc6-0242ac130003","service_id":804040,"zipcode_id":"10115","title":"title","description":"decription","date_to_be_done":"2018-11-11T00:00:00+00:00","created_at":"2019-12-11T14:55:48+00:00"}'
+'{"id":"a961c741-1c32-11ea-bfc6-0242ac130003","service_id":804040,"zipcode_id":"10115","title":"title","description":"decription","date_to_be_done":"2018-11-11T00:00:00+00:00","created_at":"2019-12-11T20:43:36+00:00"}'
```

As you see the response looks identical except the created at part.

How can i ignore the created_at from the response.

Comment: One option would be to transform to array, unset created_at and compare.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i though about the same idea, but i am not sure, if this is the best practise

Answer (score 2):

A common approach would be to `json_decode()` the content and then only compare the data that is interesting to you, e.g. id, service_id, zipcode_id, ...

If you want to actually do time sensitive tests, e.g. checking when a job is done, you could use something like Symfony's PHPUnitBridge to "freeze" time using [Clock Mocking](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#clock-mocking). This is not suited for your WebTestCase and more for a unit test. This is roughly how it would look if you want to check for the created_at-timestamp:

```php
class Job
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createdAt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', time());
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}

---

/**
 * @group time-sensitive
 */
public function testJobCreatedAtIsSetToCurrentTime(): void
{
    $job = new Job();

    $this->assertSame(time(), $job->getCreatedAt()->format('U'));
}
```

If you want to have something similar for your WebTestCase or you want to test more complex scenarios where only certain times are "frozen", the best approach I can think of is refrain from using `DateTime`/`DateTimeImmutable`, `date()`, etc. and instead have a Clock service which is injected into services for providing the time. This requires some additional work and complexity, but makes time-based testing more reliable. Having a service that provides time allows it to be replaced for testing purposes with a "FrozenClock". There is a library which you can use: [lcobucci/clock](https://github.com/lcobucci/clock), but you could easily write something that fits your needs better. This is how the previous test would look like, if I used the library instead:

```php
class Job
{
    public function __construct(Clock $clock)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $clock->now();
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}

---

public function testJobCreatedAtIsSetToCurrentTime(): void
{
    $clock = new FrozenClock(new DateTimeImmutable('2019-12-11T14:55:48+00:00'));
    $job = new Job();

    $this->assertSame('2019-12-11T14:55:48+00:00', $job->getCreatedAt()->format(DateTime::ATOM));
}
```

For your web test case in your `test/services.yaml` you would change whatever service is aliased to the Clock-interface to a FrozenClock-service with a fixed time to ensure each service requiring a clock uses that time.